# Is there an equivalent of ESCAPE_NON_ASCII feature for csvGenerator?

Tags: java, csv, utf-8, jackson, fasterxml

I am trying to encode special characters of a string (like a \n) in utf-8 with Jackson, but only found out how to do it with JsonGenerator :

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.getFactory().configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII, true);
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode node = objectMapper.getNodeFactory().objectNode();
node.put("test", "un\ndeux");
```

Is there a way to do it so I can use it as a csv and not Json?

To give more details, my problem is when I generate the CSV in Postman, it show something like : 
`un
deux`
so it loses the csv format.
I want to be able to keep the csvformat while knowing I have a \n character between "un" and "deux".

Comment: Can you provide an exemple of how you use the CsvMapper? The only chars to escape in csv is double quotes usually. If you want to escape other chars then do it directly in java

Comment: Try `node.put("test", "un\\ndeux");` or `node.put("test", "\"un\ndeux\"");`

Comment: @alain.janinm I know that it could be a solution, but I want it to work for every other special character (if there are some)

Comment: There are libs to do that, for example : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html. And it has a special method named `escapeCsv`.